# Error While Pushing Code to Heroku using Git

Tags: git, heroku

I am getting this error after running

`git push heroku master` command

> fatal: unable to access 'https://git.heroku.com/afternoon-sands-50963.git/': Failed to connect to git.heroku.com port 443: Connection refused

Answer (score -1):

Try removing your Heroku remote reference, then re-adding it and adding keys. Use the below commands:

```
git remote rm heroku
```

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:afternoon-sands-50963.git
```

```
heroku keys:add
```